# Confused with Global and local variable access

Tags: javascript, storage

Its bad form of naming same variable in different scope though.
Still curios to know how it works in this manner.

I am using variable named number under many scopes need to know the way to access parent and grand-parent scope variable.

```
var number = 2;
var bool = true;
var fun = function(numbs){

    console.log(number);
    //here it displays 2

    var number =numbs;
    console.log(number);
    //here it  displays 3


    console.log(window.number);
    //i can get global variable value here

    if(bool){

        var number = 4
        console.log(number);

        //here it display 4

        console.log(window.number);
        //here it display 2



        console.log();
        // how do i get 3 which is variable in the parent scope
    }
}

fun(3);
```

Comment: console.log( numbs );

Comment: `var` used to declare a variable. So in your `if` condition you overwritten the parent `number` variables declaration and definition completely.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a variable in a scope, you can't access a variable with the same name declared in a greater scope (except global, using `window`).

But also note the scope of `var` is the current function (not the current block), so when you use `var number = 4` you are overwriting  the number declared above.

If you really  want to name those variables equal, you could try

```
var scope1 = {
    number: 2,
    bool: true
};
(function(numbs){
    var scope2 = {}, scope3 = {};
    console.log(scope1.number); // 2
    scope2.number = numbs;
    console.log(scope2.number); // 3
    console.log(scope1.number); // 2
    if(scope1.bool){
        scope3.number = 4
        console.log(scope3.number); // 4
        console.log(scope1.number); // 2
        console.log(scope2.number); // 3
    }
})(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know about [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) in JavaScript. Also, JavaScript has functional scope and not block scope the way you are expecting.

```
someVariable = 10;

var someVariable;

//Turns out to be:

var someVariable;
console.log(someVariable); // undefined
someVariable = 10;
```

So your function actually turns out to be :

```
var fun = function (numbs) {
    var number;
    console.log(number);
    //here it displays undefined and not 2.

    number = numbs;
    console.log(number);
    //here it  displays 3

    console.log(window.number);
    //i can get global variable value here

    if (bool) {

        number = 4
        console.log(number);
        //here it display 4

        console.log(window.number);
        //here it display 2

        console.log();
        // how do i get 3 which is variable in the parent scope
        // No parent scope either global or local scope, use numbs
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry but this:

```
console.log(number);
//here it displays 2
```

doesn't display 2 I don't think, because `number` is undefined at that point.

```
number = 2; // <-- global variable
var number = 2; // <-- not global
```

EDIT: I know this doesn't explicitly answer your question, but it may implicitly answer it